# Match multiple criteria in Excel

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to count number of times a condition that can be true based on whether the condition matches, and if the date is within a certain range.

I want result in column `F` based on these conditions:

- If Columns `A` and `H` match than
- If Column `B` is less than or equal to column `I` than

  - Column `C` and `J` match
  - Column `D` and `K` match

If column `A` and `H` matches and rest of the 3 conditions also match, than I want to find how many times all the 4 conditions have been true?

For example, in the image below, `123abc` in cell A2 matches with `H4` and `H6`. Similarly the rest 3 conditions are also true, so count is 2. Hence, `F2` cell should have result as `2`.

***Alternatively***, I also tried to pull in the dates in `I4` and `I6` in result cell `F2` when the conditions are true. But no luck!

I figured an array formula with `INDEX`/`MATCH`, but have not been successful. The formula I tried is:

```
{=IFERROR(A2=INDEX($H$2:$H$10,MATCH(1,(($I$2:$I$10>=B2)*($J$2:$J$10=C2)*($K$2:$K$10=D2)),0)),"NA")}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

EDIT1:

My data looks similar to this:

```
|   A    |      B     |  C  |  D  | E | F |   G    |      H     |  I  |  J  |
|--------|------------|-----|-----|---|---|--------|------------|-----|-----|
| 123abc | 10/24/2018 | XYZ | 123 |   |   | 234xyz | 4/29/2018  | XYZ | 234 |
| 234xyz | 1/21/2019  | ABC | 234 |   |   | 456abc | 4/30/2018  | ABC | 456 |
| 789pqr | 4/30/2018  | PQR | 789 |   |   | 123abc | 10/24/2018 | ABC | 123 |
|        |            |     |     |   |   | 234xyz | 3/29/2019  | XYZ | 234 |
|        |            |     |     |   |   | 123abc | 3/20/2019  | ABC | 123 |
|        |            |     |     |   |   | 501xyz | 4/30/2018  | XYZ | 501 |
|        |            |     |     |   |   | 789pqr | 3/30/2018  | PQR | 789 |
|        |            |     |     |   |   | 789pqr | 4/30/2018  | PQR | 789 |
|        |            |     |     |   |   | 310jkl | 4/30/2017  | JKL | 310 |
```

|

[image: Data Sample]

Comment: I think a simple COUNTIFS would suffice. Please share also an editable version of your data (e.g. format it [here](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) so we can test solutions before proposing it

Comment: "I figured an array formula with INDEX/MATCH" INDEX / MATCH are generally used to retrieve individual items, but you need to aggregate data, I don't think this approach could work.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: Hi Thank you for quick response. I have added the table as you said.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your problem you can use this formula:
`=COUNTIFS(H:H,A1,I:I,">="&B1,J:J,C1,K:K,D1)`

[image]

In your example table there is only one match: A3 to H8

Comment: Yes! But for me the result is displayed like this: `1/0/1900` for all the rows. When I paste-special, I get 0. I have also checked the format. Its general. Even if I change it to number, I still get the result as 0.

Comment: That's the reason, I mentioned, alternatively I tried pulling the dates as well. Something like this: `{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($H$2:$H$10=A7,IF($I$2:$I$10>B7,IF($J$2:$J$10=C2,IF($K$2:$K$10=D2,$I$2:$I$10,""),""))))}`. But no luck!

Comment: From the sample data you've posted only this cell is 1, others are 0. Do you get different result from the one in my spreadsheet? Are your data stored as data or are they text?

Comment: My data is stored as data. So columns A, C, D, H, J, K are in general format. While columns B & I are stored as date format.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a combination of `IF` and `AND`, it's looks convoluted but it does the work and returns the numbers of `True` value checks.

```
=IF(A2=H2;
    IF(AND(A2=H2;YB2<=I2);
        IF(AND(A2=H2;YB2<=I2;C2=J2);
           IF(AND(A2=H2;YB2<=I2;C2=J2;D2=K2);
"True 4 Times";"True 3 Times");"True 2 Times");"True 1 Time");"Never True")
```

Tried my best to go for clarity on the formula but it's long and sintax doesn't help a lot.

For stuff like this I find easier to make a small macro function rather than using matrix formulas.

Cheers

Comment: Your formula compares only within one row, the question ask comparing one row of left range to all rows in right range.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Doesn't seem like it, there is a logic of `if`s  explained by OP.

Comment: "For example, in the image below, 123abc in cell A2 matches with H4 and H6. Similarly the rest 3 conditions are also true, so count is 2. Hence, F2 cell should have result as 2."

Comment: @MátéJuhász "_If Columns A and H match than_ > _If Column B is less than or equal to column I than__ > __Column C and J match_ > _Column D and K match_"

Comment: @dmb: Thanks for the response. But I want to compare `A2` with the range `H2:H10`. And the same with Columns B to D through Columns I to K.